# Cocos2d-x animation

Tags: animation, sprite, sprite-sheet, cocos2d-x-2.x

Hello I'm doing a project. I wanted to know how to animate my character. I follow the guide in cocos wiki but I can't make it possible on my code.

My character can move and walk, I want to apply an animation when he jumps.It has a `onKeyPressed` method. I don't know how to change the normal sprite to the movement `spritesheet`, I have the `plist` but I don't know how to load in my code.

I tried so many tutorials but I don't know how to implement them in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple player movement and animation tutorial, you can find it [here](http://war1oc.tumblr.com/post/99737913733/cocos2d-x-player-movement-and-animation).
You can also get the entire source code for this [here](https://github.com/war1oc/cocos2d-x-player).

However this tutorial does not use any spritesheet, I tried to keep it as simple as possible. To use spritesheets, you will need to do some modifications:

In your scene's "init()" method, you need to add a SpriteBatchNode object and add the plist file to the SpriteFrameCache singleton.

```
auto spriteBatch = SpriteBatchNode::create("sprites/sprite_sheet.png", 200);
auto spriteFrameCache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
spriteFrameCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("sprites/sprite_sheet.plist");
this->addChild(spriteBatch, kMiddleground);
```

Then add the player object to the SpriteBatchNode

```
player = Player::create();
spriteBatch->addChild(player);
```

Then in the player class, create the animations like this:

```
SpriteFrameCache* cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
Vector<SpriteFrame*> moveAnimFrames(10); // parameter = number of frames you have for this anim
char str[100] = {0};

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // this 10 is again the number of frames
{
    sprintf(str, "move_%d.png", i);
    SpriteFrame* frame = cache->getSpriteFrameByName( str );
    moveAnimFrames.pushBack(frame);
}

moveAnimation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(moveAnimFrames, 0.011f);
moveAnimation->setLoops(-1);
moveAnimate = Animate::create(moveAnimation);
moveAnimate->retain(); // retain so you can use it again
this->runAction(moveAnimate); // run the animation
```

You can create different animations and change them by:

```
this->stopAction(moveAnimate);
this->runAction(jumpAnimate);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any idea how to run the animation with the sprites flipped horizontally ? i tried doing mySprite->setFlippedX(true), but it doesn't seem to flip the animation sprites... any idea ? I've been struggling to figure this out...